# How to pass the “user_data_mapper” argument to beam pipeline’s WriteToSnowflake function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pipeline, apache-beam-io

I am trying to create a pipeline for writing the data to snowflakes using apache beam. For writing the data I am using WriteToSnowflakes function, but I am getting below error message.

**TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'user_data_mapper'**

When I searched regarding this argument, I founded this link
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/snowflake/#required-parameters-1
but I am not able understand this function. what this ‘user’ argument means, how and where to define it and what data has to be passed to this function from the pipeline. Can any one please help me with some sample code for this argument.

The sample code :

```
     with TestPipeline(options=PipelineOptions(OPTIONS)) as p:
      (p
       
       | <SOURCE OF DATA>
       | WriteToSnowflake(
       server_name=<SNOWFLAKE SERVER NAME>,
       username=<SNOWFLAKE USERNAME>,
       password=<SNOWFLAKE PASSWORD>,
       schema=<SNOWFLAKE SCHEMA>,
       database=<SNOWFLAKE DATABASE>,
       staging_bucket_name=<GCS OR S3 BUCKET>,
       storage_integration_name=<SNOWFLAKE STORAGE INTEGRATION NAME>,
       table_schema=<SNOWFLAKE TABLE SCHEMA>,
       table=<SNOWFLAKE TABLE>,
       create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
       write_disposition= 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
       
      )
```

Comment: Can you share to us your current `WriteToSnowflake()` class implementation?

Comment: Have you tried to take at look a this documentation [link](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.snowflake.html#apache_beam.io.snowflake.WriteToSnowflake) showing `user_data_mapper` function example?

Comment: In the above mentioned link example , i am not sure about what the word 'user' the parameter they pass mean .

Comment: `user` variable represents the multi-element data set *aka*  [Pcollection](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pcollections) which needs to be serialized in string values via `user_data_mapper` function.